# Mongoose self nesting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'd like to store the following:

```
var TestSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    regions: [RegionSchema]
}

var RegionSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    minX: {
        type: Number
    },
    minY: {
        type: Number
    },
    minZ: {
        type: Number
    },
    maxX: {
        type: Number
    },
    maxY: {
        type: Number
    },
    maxZ: {
        type: Number
    },
    children: [this]
});
```

So as you can see I'm trying to make a region object, able to contain region objects, however this fails to save without exception, presumably the [this] in the schema gets stuck in some endless loop or something.

How can I make this to work for nesting regions?

The json payload I could expect to send to this schema:

```
name: "test123",
regions: [
        {
            name: "TestRegion",
            minX: 0,
            minY: 0,
            minZ: 0,
            maxX: 100,
            maxY: 255,
            maxZ: 100,
            children: [
                {
                    name: "TestRegionChild",
                    minX: 3,
                    minY: 3,
                    minZ: 3,
                    maxX: 97,
                    maxY: 252,
                    maxZ: 97,
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your other regions are saved first, you can save the children as a list of objectIds like this:

```
children: [{
     type: Schema.ObjectId,
     ref: 'Region'
}]
```

Another option is to redesign your Schema and have a 'parent' on your Region and delete the 'children' field. Then when you need to get all the children you can query easily and not have big nested objects.

```
var RegionSchema = new Schema({
     --- other fields omitted ---

     parent: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Region'
    }
});
```